# How to read CSV in pandas when one column is pipe delimted?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, csv, dataframe

Hi I have a CSV structured like this

```
ColA          ColB
entry1    A|B|C|D|E|F
```

I want to read the file in pandas using the `read_csv` method I need the output to be

```
ColA    ColB1 colB2 colB3 ...
entry1    A     B     C   ...
```

What is the cleanest way to achieve this?

Comment: not sure if that is possible, I think ur best bet would be to read in the data, then perform the split in ColB after

Comment: What have you tried already? How did that fail? There's no evidence here that you've made a good-faith effort to solve this yourself. If you need someone to write code for you, there are services for that, StackOverflow isn't one of them.

Comment: I tried `pd.read_csv('data.csv', sep="|")` which didn't work. Hence the use of "cleanest" in my post, I wanted to see if there was a one liner to do this, but maybe there is not that is why I am asking.

Answer (score 2):

Let's say `test.csv` is:

```
ColA;ColB
entry1;A|B|C|D|E|F
```

Here is a solution:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('test.csv', sep=';')
df[['ColB1','ColB2', 'ColB3', 'ColB4', 'ColB5', 'ColB6']] = df['ColB'].str.split("|",expand=True,)
df = df.drop(columns=['ColB'])
print(df)
```

Output:

```
     ColA ColB1 ColB2 ColB3 ColB4 ColB5 ColB6
0  entry1     A     B     C     D     E     F
```

Source: https://cmdlinetips.com/2018/11/how-to-split-a-text-column-in-pandas/

Comment: This looks good but what about if different rows in `colB` have a different number of elements? For instance row 1 is `A|B|C|D|E|F` but row 2 might be `foo|bar` and row 3 could be `peanut butter|chocolate|cookie|ice cream` and row 4 might be `A|B|C|D|E|F|G|H` for instance, how can I account for this?

Comment: Good question @mafyiful! Perhaps, you can preprocess the CSV to add enough `|` as a suffix to the relevant data. But obviously you're outside of the classic CSV scope, it's rather a "custom file format" that you have here, with two separators chars and a variable number of columns for each row, so I would rather loop on each line and parse manually, before feeding to `pandas`.